# Building a linked list with LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, sorting, linked-list

What is the fastest way to order an unordered list of elements by predecessor (or parent) element index using LINQ?

Each element has a unique ID and the ID of that element's predecessor (or parent) element, from which a linked list can be built to represent an ordered state.

### Example

```
ID      | Predecessor's ID
--------|--------------------
20      | 81
81      | NULL
65      | 12
12      | 20
120     | 65
```

The sorted order is {81, 20, 12, 65, 120}. An (ordered) linked list can easily be assembled iteratively from these elements, but can it be done in fewer LINQ statements?

**Edit:** I should have specified that IDs are not necessarily sequential. I chose 1 to 5 for simplicity. See updated element indices which are random.

Comment: Is "index" related to *order*, or is it just *any* identifier?

Comment: Index can be any identifier. See clarifying edits.

Comment: @FreshCode Can there be multiple "root" Nodes, that is Nodes without a predecessor?

Comment: @Michael: No. Assume there is only one root.

Comment: how is the sorted order in your example *{81, 20, 12, 65, 120}* ? If you want to order by predecessor index it should be  *{81, 65, 12, 120, 20}*

Comment: @BrokenGlass, the first node is 81 (no predecessor). The second node is 20, since its predecessor is 81 (the first node). The third node is 12, since its predecessor is 20 (the second node), et cetera. It's a reversed linked list.

Comment: @Freshcode yea, after the last edit of the question that's now clear, thanks

Answer (score 6):

Assuming that "index" has nothing to do with ordering (just an ID), let's say declared this way:

```
public class Node
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int? PredID { get; set; }
}
```

Then you could build up a map from predecessor to successor, and then follow the links.  This isn't *pure* LINQ however, but is readable and quite efficient:

```
public static LinkedList<int> GetLinkedList(IEnumerable<Node> nodes)
{
    if(nodes == null)
       throw new ArgumentNullException("nodes");

    return new LinkedList<int>(GetOrderedNodes(nodes.ToList()));
}

private static IEnumerable<int> GetOrderedNodes(IEnumerable<Node> nodes)
{
    // Build up dictionary from pred to succ.
    var links = nodes.Where(node => node.PredID != null)
                     .ToDictionary(node => node.PredID, node => node.ID);

    // Find the head, throw if there are none or multiple.
    var nextId = nodes.Single(node => node.PredID == null).ID;

    // Follow the links.
    do
    {
        yield return nextId;

    } while (links.TryGetValue(nextId, out nextId));
}
```

**EDIT**: Here's a horribly inefficient but functional solution.

The idea is that an element's index must be 1 + its predecessor's index, which is easy to specify recursively. The base, case, of course, is the head - a node whose predecessor's ID is `null`.

```
static LinkedList<int> GetLinkedList(IEnumerable<Node> nodes)
{
    return new LinkedList<int>
           (  from node in nodes
              orderby GetIndex(nodes, node)
              select node.ID
           );                                       
}


static int GetIndex(IEnumerable<Node> nodes, Node node)
{
    return node.PredID == null ? 0 :
           1 + GetIndex(nodes, nodes.Single(n => n.ID == node.PredID));
}
```

It's possible to improve the second solution *somewhat* by first creating a map from successor to predecessor. It's still nowhere as performant as the imperative solution though.

**EDIT**: Turned first solution into an iterator block.

Comment: Yours is a nice iterative solution and while iteration should trump recursion, I was hoping LINQ has an elegant functional way of dealing with this that "just works", but would probably require recursion.

Comment: @Ani, how about passing a node dictionary to `GetIndex` instead of an enumerable list of nodes?

Comment: @FreshCode: I did that, but the performance is still not linear (although it's better than the naive recurseion). Didn't want to clutter it up with too much code. On the bright side, I turned the imperative soln into an iterator, which I suppose is closer to LINQ than before.

Comment: @Ani, I ended up with the exact same iterative solution; I think it's optimal. Well done on the iterator block - more reusable.

Comment: Why are you calling ToList()? It only hurts performance.  (You don't enumerate it twice)

Comment: @SLaks: It's not necessary, but it materializes the results. And I *am* enumerating it twice: `ToDictionary` and `Single`.

Comment: @SLaks: I could dodge it of course, e.g. getting it from the dictionary. I didn't think about this *that* deeply; this is only an outline.

Comment: You can't get it from the dictionary because of the `Where` clause.  (and removing it afterwards would defeat the purpose)

Comment: @SLaks: Haha, yes - I have forgotten my own code. I did another one for the functional version that went from successor to predecessor (including the head), but didn't put it in, which is why I confused myself. What I should have said is that we could find the head in the same pass over the source, so we don't *really* need to materialize the source beforehand.

Answer (score -1):

For ordering the fact that the nodes are linked is irrelevant, just the ids matter. That being the case you can just use [OrderBy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.orderby.aspx), which in this case will put the nullable int at the top, then sort ascending.

```
public class ListNode
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int? Predecessor { get; set; }
}


List<ListNode> myList = new List<ListNode> {
                                new ListNode() { Id = 2, Predecessor = 1},
                                new ListNode() { Id = 1, Predecessor = null},
                                new ListNode() { Id = 5, Predecessor = 4},
                                new ListNode() { Id = 3, Predecessor = 2},
                                new ListNode() { Id = 4, Predecessor = 3}};


var sortedbyPredecessor = myList.OrderBy(n => n.Predecessor).ToList();
```

Comment: Indices are not necessarily sequential. See edits with clarification.